# How can $1 + 2 + 3 + ... = -\frac{1}{12}$?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Recently there's been a lot of buzz created by this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-I6XTVZXww which states and goes on to prove

$$1 + 2 + 3 + ... = -\frac{1}{12} $$

I know that the above series is actually $\zeta(-1)$ where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function. For someone who is not much into higher and advanced mathematics, what meaning does this equation hold? The video explain that this is a very useful result used in string theory in Physics and the basic premise which is used to prove it is

$$1-1+1-1+... = \frac{1}{2} $$ which doesn't seem quite right and which, in fact, leads to contradictions as explained here on Quora http://www.quora.com/Mathematics/Theoretically-speaking-how-can-the-sum-of-all-positive-integers-be-1-12/answer/David-Joyce-11. So, my question is is the proof shown in the video meaningless and only serve the purpose of sensationalizing by wrongly interpreting and misrepresenting mathematical results?

Comment: This question is frequently asked by some users in this site.  Did you do the quick search?

Comment: Yes I did but couldn't find a similar question. Please give the link and I will delete my question.

Comment: I know what this equation means. See the end part of my question. It isn't exactly the same, though the title is the same.

Comment: The interesting part of the mentioned video is NOT the derivation, but is in the beginning of the video. It shew that a book has in fact included the quoted claim. It is a bit disappointed of not knowing (1) what that book is; (2) why is it included; (3) how the claimed result can be applied.