# How come that $sum$ of $all$ positive integers equal a negative rational number

Tags: number-theory

How come that $sum$ of $all$ positive integers equal a negative rational number.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n = \frac{-1}{12}$$

[(original screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzzqY.gif)

Comment: See http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/

Comment: shouldn't $n$ be $i$?

Comment: This has been asked many times before. I would suggest that you use the search function for finding out whether your question has been answered before you ask it.

Comment: As your question is written now, it doesn't make much sense, please add some context. Even if this is meant as a joke (apologies if it's not) it would make your question less likely to get downvoted.

Comment: See [Wikipedia on 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ⋯](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

Comment: This is an invalid extension of the fact that $\zeta(-1)=-\frac1{12}$. I show that $\zeta(-1)=-\frac1{12}$ in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/632862). The series is divergent using the [Term Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does $1+2+3+\dots = {-1\over 12}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/why-does-123-dots-1-over-12).  Also: [(1)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646834/12345-frac112-is-there-any-intuition-for-this) [(2)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642768/how-can-1-2-3-frac112) [(3)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354265/1234-1-12)

Comment: This is like the 80th time I've seen this question.

Comment: By the way, it doesn't, not under the usual meanings of sum and equals. There are ways of extending the meaning of "sum" to make this equality hold, but I just thought we should get that basic fact clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been explained on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) and probably elsewhere on Stackexchange. There are a few ways to understand it, depending on how you understand the series:

- We are extrapolating the partial sums of the series, which increase with $n$, backward, and it turns out that the correct extrapolation crosses zero to reach a negative number.
- The leading term of the asymptotic expansion is certainly positive, but that doesn't prevent the constant term from being negative.
- We are crossing a simple pole in the Riemann zeta function, so we pass from positive values through infinity to negative values. (And we are stopping short of the first trivial zero, so we don't pass back into positive values.)
- The discretization of the field modes between two conducting plates leads to a positive pressure which is slightly less than the pressure from the modes outside the plates, so the Casimir force ends up being attractive.
- The second Bernoulli number is positive, and the Euler-Maclaurin formula formally contributes the negative sign. I'm sure these two facts have many more explanations, individually.

Answer (score 1):

What is true is that
$$
\lim_{r\to-1^+}\sum_{n=1}^\infty nr^{n-1}=\frac14
$$
This limit could be considered a justification for
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}n=\frac14
$$
But the erroneous step is to claim that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}n
&=\color{#00A000}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty n}-2\color{#C00000}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2n}\\
&=-3\sum_{n=1}^\infty n
\end{align}
$$
because the red sum represents the even terms of the green sum. This manipulation is only valid if the green sum is convergent.

Comment: The last manipulation also turns out to be valid if each sum is (successfully) regularized as a Dirichlet series. So singling out that step as "erroneous" and saying "only valid if ... convergent" is slightly overstating the case. I understand that we don't want the kids at home to abuse similar manipulations where they don't apply. On the other hand, I don't want them to think that rigorous methods can't explain what's going on.

Comment: @ChrisCulter: perhaps I am missing your point or you are missing mine. Since $\lim\limits_{s\to0^+}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{\Large n^s}=\frac12$, as far as we can take the limit of Dirichlet series *which actually converge* is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}=\frac12$. Pushing $s$ to $-1$ takes us outside the neighborhood of an actually convergent series.

Comment: We can't get to $s=-1$ with a limit, but we can with analytic continuation, which is part of the definition of zeta function regularization. This is explained in more detail on Wikipedia and on Padilla's website: http://www.nottingham.ac.uk/~ppzap4/response.html

Comment: @ChrisCulter: yes, I understand the concept of regularization. I am simply pointing out how far we can get without analytic continuation. To make this clearer, I have removed the work regularization from my answer.

Comment: Sure, well, it might be better to say precisely that, instead of the absolute characterizations "erroneous" and "only valid if". C'mon, those are fightin' words! :)

Comment: @ChrisCulter: my point is that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n$ *diverges* unless we give some alternate meaning to the term *convergence*. What I said in my answer is true unless the terminology is redefined somehow. This redefinition should be made clear. Using standard definitions, $$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty n&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2+n}{2}\\&=\infty\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes, the series diverges. I wouldn't want to redefine convergence. The alternating series $1-2+3-4+\cdots$ diverges, yet it is Abel summable, and the Abel sum is defined as a certain limit. The positive series $1+2+3+4+\cdots$ diverges and is not Abel summable, yet it is zeta function regularizable, and the zeta-regularized sum is defined as a certain analytic continuation. These methods are all well-defined; one is not more valid than the other. So I don't see a reason to allow only one of them.

Comment: @ChrisCulter: I am not saying that we deny the use of regularization. I am simply saying that it would be good to declare that we are using it when we do. If we declare that we are not using normal summation, perhaps so many people won't say $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n=-\frac12$ without qualification.

Comment: Agreed, that would be ideal! But then, what does it mean to say "This limit could be considered a justification for ..." in the first step? If we decide that the usual interpretation of the summation symbol must be assumed unless it is explicitly overridden, then that step is also plainly false.